# Who chained up Subotai and for what reason?

Tags: conan-the-barbarian-1982

When Conan first meets Subotai the latter is chained to a rock and expecting to be eaten by starving wolves- why was he chained to said rock and by whom?

Comment: Subotai the Thief? Hmm, I wonder what he could be been up to...

Answer (score 5):

The film's [official novelisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conan_the_Barbarian_(1982_novel)), based on a slightly earlier version of the script,  gives us some insight into Subodai's fall from grace. In short, he tried to steal from the witch and was magicked into submission (possibly during sexy-time), then tied up.

> “Food!” the prisoner croaked. “I starve, barbarian! I've had no food for days.”
>   “Who says you’ll have some now?” scowled Conan. "What are you doing here?”
>   “I’m dinner for the wolves, pets of the witch-woman. **She put a spell on me and bound me here.** Just leave me food, so I may have the strength, when the wolves come, to die fighting like a man.”
>   “Who are you?” rumbled Conan.
>   The small man rose and faced Conan with a dignity that belied his misery and his rags. “I am Subotai, a Hyrkanian of the Kerlait tribe. In happier days, an archer, an assassin, and a thief.”
>
> ...
>
> “Then why were you trussed up out here for wolf bait?” **“I did not know it was a witch from whom I tried to steal. She caught me in the web of her enchantments, as she did you.** Now, thanks to you, I have no need to steal.”